# How can I store many Django model types in a database and access them as an object?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Django models:

```
Bar, Bistro and Restaurant
```

Each of the above establishment has their own menu items, for instance:

1. Bar

   - Burger
   - Fries
   - ...
2. Bistro

   - Pasta
   - Pizza
   - ...
3. Restaurant

   - Duck
   - Wings
   - ...

I have different type of images in my home page, a main banner, left side bar and right side bar.  Each of those images will have links to menu items across the Bar, Bistro and Restaurant.  I'm currently hard-coding the urls for each of those images in the admin:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    alt_name = models.CharField
    source = models.ImageField
    url = models.CharField
```

The above is working fine but if one of the menu item changes, I will have to go back to the admin and re-write the new url.  I'm thinking of improving my admin to make it look like the following:

[image]

Selecting the appropriate establishment will populate the proper menu items. In the backend, the database will store a string corresponding to the type of establishment along with a primary key of a menu item related to that establishment.  I need the establishment association because the menu items are stored in their own tables(BarMenuItem, BistroMenuItem and RestaurantMenuItem).

Given a string `Bistro`, is it possible to retrieve its corresponding model of the same name in Django?  I believe I might have gone overboard with the above solution, let me know of your thoughts if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given a string Bistro, is it possible to retrieve its corresponding model of the same name in Django?

Yes.

```
model = ContentType.objects.get(model='Bistro').model_class()
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: A thought about the approach: maybe you should use the ContentType framework to have foreign-keys in the Image class, and have callables that compute `url` according to the values of the linked objects?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, let me give it a shot.